# Nuxt 3 package import specifier "#internal/nitro" is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I tried installing the new version of [Nuxt.js](http://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/quick-start#new-project) with command:

```
npx nuxi init nuxt-app
```

Then tried just run and project in Nuxt 3 works fine. But when I tried run this command:

```
npm run generate
```

Get this error message:

> ERROR  [nuxt] [request error] Package import specifier
> "#internal/nitro" is not defined in package
> C:\Users\Andreas\Projects\nuxt3-app\package.json imported from
> C:\Users\Andreas\Projects\nuxt3-app.nuxt\dist\server\server.mjs   at
> new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)   at throwImportNotDefined
> (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:442:9)   at packageImportsResolve
> (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:819:3)   at moduleResolve
> (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:973:21)   at defaultResolve
> (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1080:11)   at ESMLoader.resolve
> (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:30)   at ESMLoader.getModuleJob
> (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:18)   at ModuleWrap.
> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:40)   at link
> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36)

My `package.json` source code:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.1"
  }
}
```

- Node version: **16.14.1**
- NPM version: **8.5.0**

Comment: Im not sure, but I guess your npm is trying to find the module `#internal/nitro` on your package.json which is `dist\server\server.mjs` is trying to load,

Comment: Got the same issue. Any solutions with `ssr: true` so far?

Comment: I don't have any solution for this yet. @wittgenstein

Comment: Thanks - [seems from the discussion](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/560) its not supported at this time

Answer (score 6):

(Irrelevant solution, as this issue was in an RC version. Only leaving this solution for archive purposes. If you are using Nuxt and encounter this error, chances likely that this is not the correct solution. Please find another one)

-- Original comment --

I randomly fixed this issue by setting

```js
// nuxt.config.ts

  ssr: false
```

Hope its the case for you too.

> With client side rendering only there is no server-side rendering. Client side rendering means rendering the content in the browser using JavaScript. Instead of getting all of the content from the HTML we just get a basic HTML document with a JavaScript file that will then render the rest of the site using the browser. For client side rendering set ssr to false.

Link to [configuration-ssr documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-ssr/) 
Link to [rendering-modes documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/rendering-modes/)

Comment: Same error happened when i tried to install `@nuxt/ui` and this worked for me, thanks.

Comment: No, you don't need to disable SSR for static pages: you can build them at build time. This is not a fix, since you're fallbacking to using an SPA here. Just a matter of side-effect fixing the issue.

Comment: @kissu you are correct. However, at the time of writing my original post, Nuxt had an issue where `ssr: true` caused builds to fail. I hope you understand

Comment: @nopeless, is there an update on this? Has Nuxt fixed this on their end?

Comment: @RizaKhan Yes. and Nuxt has been stable for a while now. If you are getting that exact error, chances are your project is using an outdated version of nuxt

Comment: i found my issue happen when i did a pnpm build and then running pnpm dev, if i clear the .nuxt and run pnpm dev alone, it works